# How to change assembly name in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, .net-assembly

I need to rename assembly name of DLL, after every compile, by adds increment to base name. For example

```
1 compile: Assembly name - basename1.dll
2 compile: Assembly name - basename2.dll
n compile: Assembly name - basenamen.dll
```

I cant just rename a file, because dll contains some meta information about its name. How can i do it automatically after every recompile?

I use Visual studio 2013,c#

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Go to properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

Comment: Its just a trick. I need to reload plugin,while i debug it. But i cant delete basename.dll after once it loads to application. Thats how im cheating.
P.S.
I tried to load dll to another AppDomain, but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a post build step in your project properties, something like this:

```
rename "$(TargetPath)" "newname.dll"
```

If you want to add more specific information about the file, then you can create a powershell script that reads the AssemblyInfo and adds that to the file name

Comment: I would substitute the `rename` with a custom console app to get the desired incremental effect, but the post build step would do the trick he OP looks for.